# row in a table with array every column with pdfmake

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, typescript, pdfmake

In my pdf I want each associated element in each row to be split. While instead as in the image below each column has the value attached below

```
packStruct = []
packEnergy = []
packDescriptionEnergy = []
packPrice = []

{text: 'Integration', style: 'header', alignment:'center', bold:'true', fontSize: 13},
        {
          style: 'tableExample',
          unbreakable: true,
          table: {
            headerRows: 1,
            widths: ['auto', 'auto', 'auto', 100],
            body: [
              ['Interventi Strutturali', 'Interventi Energetici','Descrizione Interventi Energetici','Prezzo Interventi Intergrati'],
              [
              this.packStruct.map(function(item) {
                return item
              }),
              this.packEnergy.map(function(item) {
                return item
              }),
              this.packDescriptionEnergy.map(function(item) {
                return item
              }),
              this.packPrice.map(function(item) {
                return item.toFixed(2) + '€'
              })
            ]
            ]
          }
        },
```

[image: screen]

expected output:
[image: screen2]

Comment: Clarification: You want to display all the values splitted by comma in a single row, instead of separate rows for each data ?

Comment: @DRASHTIDOBARIYA I try to clarify, I want each column to be divided by the same row which holds an element divided from the one below

Comment: I am still not able to understand. Please provide an expected output table that you want in the question itself. Do you want it like shown in the image?

Comment: @DRASHTIDOBARIYA i edit the post with expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
getDocumentation() {
const config = {
      table: {
        headerRows: 1,
        widths: ['*', '*', '*', '*'],
        body: [
            ['Interventi Strutturali', 'Interventi Energetici','Descrizione Interventi Energetici','Prezzo Interventi Intergrati'],
        ]
      }
};

for(let i=0;i<this.packStruct.length;i++) {
    const newRow = [];
    this.newRow.push(!!this.packStruct[i] ? this.packStruct[i] : "");
    this.newRow.push(!!this.packEnergy[i] ? this.packEnergy[i] : "");
    this.newRow.push(!!this.packDescriptionEnergy[i] ? this.packDescriptionEnergy[i] : "");
    this.newRow.push(!!this.packPrice[i] ? this.packPrice[i].toFixed(2) + '€' : "");
    config.table.body.push(newRow);
}

return {content: [config]};
}
```

You can add styling such as table borders etc according to your needs. This is the basic config for creating separate rows.

Comment: the `const` and the `for` do I have to add them outside the content []?

Comment: My project is in typescript

Comment: Yes. you have to add them outside the config. This is in typescript.

Comment: I add an answer below. Why give me the error?

Comment: with `[config]` i solved the the previous error, but now it gives me this error: `core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unrecognized document structure: {"content":[{"table":{"headerRows":1,"widths":["*","*","*","*"],"body":[["Interventi Strutturali","Interventi Energetici","Descrizione Interventi Energetici","Prezzo Interventi Integrati"],["G7","d4 b","Isolamento termico all'estradosso del solaio inferiore \r\n","315.56€"],["F3","c1","Sostituzione dei serramenti con modelli ad alta prestazione energetica*\r\n","690.22€"]]}}]}`

Answer (score 0):

I add the code like this:

```
    getDocumentDefinition() {
    
        const config = {
          table: {
            headerRows: 1,
            widths: ['*','*','*',100],
            body: [
              ['Interventi Strutturali','Interventi Energetici','Descrizione Interventi Energetici', 'Prezzo Interventi Integrati'],
            ]
          }
        }
    
        for(let i = 0; i < this.packStruct.length; i++) {
          const newRow = []
          newRow.push(!!this.packStruct[i] ? this.packStruct[i] : "");
    newRow.push(!!this.packEnergy[i] ? this.packEnergy[i] : "");
    newRow.push(!!this.packDescriptionEnergy[i] ? this.packDescriptionEnergy[i] : "");
    newRow.push(!!this.packPrice[i] ? this.packPrice[i].toFixed(2) + '€' : "");
    config.table.body.push(newRow);
        }
    
        return {
    
          content: [
            {
              table: {
                body: config
              }
            },
         ]
       }
    ] 
    }
    }
```

Is right? I don't know why he gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

But I don't know why, since it was printing the other way, so there was data in packStruct